# How do I traverse a variable from a controller to a service?

Tags: angularjs

I have written a Angular controller that stores the id of a movie in a scope/variable,

```
$scope.wishlistID.push({id: movie.id});
var movieID = $scope.wishlistID;
```

Now in my service I want to add the value of the movieID var or the value of the whislistID into the url, because at the moment I'm using a jQuery selector to get the ID.

```
service.add = function(){
  var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text();

  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + movieID + '?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=' +'&append_to_response=releases&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )

}
```

So how would I insert the ID I get in my controller into the URL at the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a parameter to accept `movieID`

```
service.add = function(movieID){
  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + movieID + '?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=' +'&append_to_response=releases&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )
}
```

usage in controller

```
var movieId = $scope.wishlistID[0].id;//better use movie.id directly

//Pass movie id
service.add(movieId);
```

Comment: Thought it was something like that, easy enough. Quick question though, is it possible to use multiple variables like that? Say I want to add the title to the search as well as the ID from the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `id` parameter to the service function as an argument:

```
//pass parameter in controller
service.add(id);

//use parameter in service function
service.add = function(id) {
    //use id in your url
}
```